# Reduce the size fo a tikz picture

Tags: graphics, tikz-pic, flow-charts

I have a flowchart created using tikz.

Example,

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
   base/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center}, 
  steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                  minimum height=1cm, text width=3cm},
process/.style = {base,
                  minimum height=2cm, text width=4cm, fill=white}
                  ]
\node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
\node (process2) [process, right=of process1]   {text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
\node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]                   {Step 1};
\node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
\node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
%
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\node[fit=(step1) (process1), fill=red!20] {};
\node[fit=(step2) (process2), fill=red!40] {};
\node[fit=(step3) (process3), fill=red!60] {};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could someone please let me know how the size of the figure created within `\begin{tikzpicture}..\end{tikzpicture}` can be reduced to 0.8 of its original size?

EDIT:
I tried scale=0.8 and it didn't work for some reason.

EDIT2: I tried the below , but both scalebox and scale aren't working

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,
                arrows,
                positioning,
                arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix}

% image
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}


% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


 \begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
% \scalebox{0.5}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5, yscale=0.5,transform shape,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
  steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                  minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                  minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                  fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white,text width=24mm,
                    inner sep=2mm, align = center},
 img/.style={inner sep=0pt,execute at begin node={%
    \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{#1}}},%added
  >=Stealth 
                  ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=1em,nodes in empty cells,
nodes={anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes=steps,execute at begin node={Step \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}},
row 6/.style={nodes={text width=9em,align=center}}]
(mat) {
 & &  \\
 |[process]| text1 & 
 |[process]| text2 &
 |[process]| text3\\ 
 |[img=im]| & |[img=im]| & |[img=im]|  \\[1em]
 |[img=im]| & |[process]| & |[img=im]|  \\[1em]
 |[img=im]| & |[img=im]| & |[img=im]|  \\[-1em]
  &  &  \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {black!2,black!5,black!15} {
 \node[fit=(mat-1-\Y) (mat-2-\Y) (mat-3-\Y) (mat-4-\Y) (mat-5-\Y) (mat-6-\Y), fill=\X]{};
}
}
\path[-Stealth]
(mat-2-1) edge (mat-2-2) 
(mat-2-2) edge (mat-2-3)
(mat-3-1) edge (mat-4-1)
(mat-4-1) edge (mat-5-1)
(mat-5-1) edge (mat-5-2)
(mat-5-2) edge (mat-4-2)
(mat-4-2) edge (mat-3-2)
(mat-3-2) edge (mat-3-3)
(mat-3-3) edge (mat-4-3)
(mat-4-3) edge (mat-5-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
% }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `scale=0.8` in the optional arguments of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @Archange It didn't work for me. I am not sure why.

Comment: Then I would use the `standalone` and `tikzscale` packages to include the above file as an external picture and set the side in `\includegraphics`. Bonus, you can then avoid recompiling the figure each time. ;)

Comment: @Archange Could you please share some examples for the same?

Comment: If you use just `scale`, you change the coordinate system alone. To change size of everything, you should use `scale=0.8, transform shape`.

Comment: Even `transform shape` returns an incorrect picture, since the `fit` nodes aren't sized correctly. I wonder why.

Comment: @Natasha I’ve added an example as an answer.

Comment: transform shape didn't work either

Comment: @Natasha, I added an answer

Comment: @SebGlav it seems that the `inner sep` parameter of the `fit` nodes is not scaled correctly. I do not know if it's a bug or a feature ;-) .

Comment: @SebGlav Could you please check my edit 2? The overleaf file can be found here overleaf.com/4445333513vpytnytxkvqc

Comment: Your example does not compile, the "im" graphic file is missing here. Anyway, with such a complex graphic, I would prepare it in standalone class as in your first example, generate a PDF, and then include the PDF in your article with a simple `includegraphics` (that you can scale easily).  The graphic does not scale because you use a lot of explicit sizes there.

Comment: @Rmano That’s what I’ve been proposing almost from the start, and actually what we implemented in the overleaf. Excepted I proposed a solution not requiring compiling to PDF form and that would automatically adapt to change of e.g. main font.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to control the size of such a figure when including it, you can use `standalone` and `tikzscale` to include your example code (here saved under `figure.tex`) as a figure using the regular `\includegraphics`. See below for an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone} % Necessary to skip headers of {standalone} documents
\usepackage{tikzscale} % To use \includegraphics with TikZ code
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,positioning}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figure.tex}

\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figure.tex}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{figure.tex}

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image: example of inclusion at any given size]

Comment: Sorry for another question. How can I generate the tex file ? On overleaf, I only find .pdf_tex options for download

Comment: The `figure.tex` one you mean? It’s just your MWE saved under that name (I’ve edited my answer for clarification).

Comment: Ahh, so I create a separate figure.tex file and open it in the current main.tex file?

Comment: Exactly (“include it” is more accurate than “open it” though ;D).

Comment: I tried the same https://www.overleaf.com/4445333513vpytnytxkvqc but it isn't working. Could you please check main.tex and figure.tex in the link ?

Comment: I’ve looked at it and fixed the code. The separate `figure.tex` should really be like your MWE code, in particular using the `standalone` class (while you where using an `article` class) and all packages/headers used inside it should be reported to the `main.tex` headers. Also if you need to include it in a `figure` env, that should be done in `main.tex`.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look

Answer (score 3):

### Have to run now, [@Archange's answer is better!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618077/38080)

#### New answer, for the new version of the question: PLEASE don't do that, ask another question instead!

Ok, the graph is complex and the `matrix` environment uses a lot of catcodes changes (technicality here) so it's difficult to embed it in another command. I would do:

1. put your graph in a standalone file, like `lalla.tex` here (in overleaf, it can be in a different project; maybe you can go in the same project but I am not expert in how overleaf work (you can ask *another question*).
   So you have this file, `lalla.tex`, which is a standalone of your picture.

```latex
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,
                arrows,
                positioning,
                arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix}

% image
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% ------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
  steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                  minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                  minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                  fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white,text width=24mm,
                    inner sep=2mm, align = center},
 img/.style={inner sep=0pt,execute at begin node={%
    \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{#1}}},%added
  >=Stealth 
                  ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=1em,nodes in empty cells,
nodes={anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes=steps,execute at begin node={Step \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}},
row 6/.style={nodes={text width=9em,align=center}}]
(mat) {
 & &  \\
 |[process]| text1 & 
 |[process]| text2 &
 |[process]| text3\\ 
 |[img=im]| & |[img=im]| & |[img=im]|  \\[1em]
 |[img=im]| & |[process]| & |[img=im]|  \\[1em]
 |[img=im]| & |[img=im]| & |[img=im]|  \\[-1em]
  &  &  \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {black!2,black!5,black!15} {
 \node[fit=(mat-1-\Y) (mat-2-\Y) (mat-3-\Y) (mat-4-\Y) (mat-5-\Y) (mat-6-\Y), fill=\X]{};
}
}
\path[-Stealth]
(mat-2-1) edge (mat-2-2) 
(mat-2-2) edge (mat-2-3)
(mat-3-1) edge (mat-4-1)
(mat-4-1) edge (mat-5-1)
(mat-5-1) edge (mat-5-2)
(mat-5-2) edge (mat-4-2)
(mat-4-2) edge (mat-3-2)
(mat-3-2) edge (mat-3-3)
(mat-3-3) edge (mat-4-3)
(mat-4-3) edge (mat-5-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2. You create a PDF (`lalla.pdf`, or whatever) and then in your main project you upload the PDF, and have:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{lalla.pdf}
    \caption{here, so small}
\end{figure}

blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

To obtain:

[image]

#### Old answer, for first version of the question

Well --- if you use `standalone`, when you view the figure it will be a full page always --- the page size changes, but normally the viewer will fit it, so you can't see any difference.

Using `scale=0.5, transform shape` works for me; see the example (just the original one, with a copied `tikzpicture` environment, and a fixed-page `article` class --- yes, the first one is overfull):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center},
    steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50,
    minimum height=1cm, text width=3cm},
    process/.style = {base,
    minimum height=2cm, text width=4cm, fill=white}
    ]
    \node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
    \node (process2) [process, right=of process1]   {text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
    \node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]                   {Step 1};
    \node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
    \node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
    %
    \scoped[on background layer]
    {
        \node[fit=(step1) (process1), fill=red!20] {};
        \node[fit=(step2) (process2), fill=red!40] {};
        \node[fit=(step3) (process3), fill=red!60] {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape,
    node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center},
    steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50,
    minimum height=1cm, text width=3cm},
    process/.style = {base,
    minimum height=2cm, text width=4cm, fill=white}
    ]
    \node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
    \node (process2) [process, right=of process1]   {text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
    \node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]                   {Step 1};
    \node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
    \node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
    %
    \scoped[on background layer]
    {
        \node[fit=(step1) (process1), fill=red!20] {};
        \node[fit=(step2) (process2), fill=red!40] {};
        \node[fit=(step3) (process3), fill=red!60] {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The other possibility is to include the `tikzpicture` in a `scalebox` (from `graphicx` package); change the second picture to enclose it in a `scalebox` command:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center},
    steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50,
    minimum height=1cm, text width=3cm},
    process/.style = {base,
    minimum height=2cm, text width=4cm, fill=white}
    ]
    \node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
    \node (process2) [process, right=of process1]   {text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
    \node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]                   {Step 1};
    \node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
    \node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
    %
    \scoped[on background layer]
    {
        \node[fit=(step1) (process1), fill=red!20] {};
        \node[fit=(step2) (process2), fill=red!40] {};
        \node[fit=(step3) (process3), fill=red!60] {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center},
    steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50,
    minimum height=1cm, text width=3cm},
    process/.style = {base,
    minimum height=2cm, text width=4cm, fill=white}
    ]
    \node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
    \node (process2) [process, right=of process1]   {text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
    \node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]                   {Step 1};
    \node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
    \node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
    %
    \scoped[on background layer]
    {
        \node[fit=(step1) (process1), fill=red!20] {};
        \node[fit=(step2) (process2), fill=red!40] {};
        \node[fit=(step3) (process3), fill=red!60] {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

and you'll have *almost* the same result (there seems to be some distance in the `fit` box that does not scale the same as the rest in the first option...)

[image]

Comment: I tried scalebox. But my code didn't compile

Comment: Have you added `\usepackage{graphicx}`? (I changed the code to a full MWE now)

Comment: I will share complete working example in a bit

Comment: So I think the problem is when I include tikz picture in a figure environment.  Does the scalebox or scale=0.5 transform shape work when  `\begin{figure*} \begin{tikzpicture}` ?. I am using this to include the tikz picture in one column in a two-column document.

Comment: Could you please check my edit 2? The overleaf file can be found here https://www.overleaf.com/4445333513vpytnytxkvqc

Comment: @Rmano Your new version is basically my answer (excepted I don’t compile to PDF but include the tikz file with tikzscale). ;)

Comment: @Archange yes, you're right. Question: you input `.tex` here, I suppose you have some automatism to compile to PDF (in my local setup, a plain TeXLive with `latexmk`, which I think it's the same `overleaf` uses, it doesn't work out of the box).

Comment: Did you put `tikzscale` and `standalone` in the package list of the main file? Because it works in Overleaf, especially in @Natasha one. Also note that AFAIK, you have to report the headers of the standalone file in the main document (they are ignored when the `standalone` file is read).